# Meaning of γυναικα in 1 Tim 3:11

Tags: greek, 1-timothy, commentary

I'm looking for commentaries/publications regarding use of word 'γυναικα' in 1 Tim 3:11.

I need commentaries, which would cover following concepts:

1. γυναικα - the wife [of a Deacon]
2. γυναικα - a woman [in general]
3. γυναικα - a woman [Deacon]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_timothy/3-11.htm  and https://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_timothy/3-11.htm and https://biblehub.com/greek/1135.htm

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Just as 'man' in Greek may be a single man or a husband, so γυναῖκας is a woman or a wife. Paul uses the wording διακονον (female deacon) in referring to Phoebe in Romans 16:1. If the woman's husband is not stated, there would be no way of knowing if she is the wife of a deacon or the wife of a brother in the church.

Answer (score 0):

Wives or Deaconesses? (γυνή in 1 Tim 3:11)

[https://www.billmounce.com/monday-with-mounce/wives-or-deaconesses-γυνή-1-tim-3-11](https://www.billmounce.com/monday-with-mounce/wives-or-deaconesses-%CE%B3%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%AE-1-tim-3-11)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.